# How to apply np.where() to a search into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I got to dataframe :

- df_depart
  [df_depart visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuBwz.png)
- data_sorted_monotone
  [data_sorted_monotone visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU1Iz.png)

I would like to use as a condition the line in comment :

```
np.where(
    #   df_depart['NOM SCADA'] in data_sorted_monotone.columns,
    df_depart['NOM SCADA'] =='test',
    'smth',
    np.nan
)
```

I would like to create a new row in df_depart, this row will be filled by a value from a calcul in data_sorted_monotone.
For this i need to know when a value of the column 'Varaible_scada' is included as a column name in data_sorted_monotone. If not i won't do the calculation and fill 'Nan'.

Does somebody have a clean and fast way to do it ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Hi timebis, please avoid using images as code. Put your dataframe as code, something like `pd.DataFrame(....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let me know if I get what you are talking about, but try this:

```
df_depart['new_col'] = np.where(df_depart['NOM SCADA'].isin(data_sorted_monotone.columns), 'smth', np.nan)
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for !